# While loop or for loop for json object for android not working

Tags: android, loops, while-loop

I am trying to add a for loop or while loop for method  getuserDetailWhileLoop(); but i am having a hard time figuring out on how to do it. This code suppose to show json object to text view and text view has scroll view in it. However when i ran the code the while loop is not working and only show 1 object. I need the while loop to show multiple object. How will i be doing that? Thanks.

```
package com.demo.myblog.profile;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.android.volley.AuthFailureError;
import com.android.volley.NetworkResponse;
import com.android.volley.Request;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest;
import com.demo.myblog.R;
import com.demo.myblog.volley.VolleySingleton;

import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class UserProfile extends AppCompatActivity {
    private String ID,NAME,EMAIL,CREATED_DATE, ID2;
    private String appURl, appURl2;
    Activity mContext = this;
    TextView mId,mName,mEmail,mDate, mid2;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_user_profile2);

        mId = findViewById(R.id.txt_Id);
        mid2 = findViewById(R.id.textView5);
        mName = findViewById(R.id.txt_Name);
        mEmail = findViewById(R.id.txt_Email);
        mDate = findViewById(R.id.txt_Data);


        Intent data = getIntent();
        EMAIL = data.getStringExtra("email");
        appURl = "url here";
        appURl2 = "url2 here";

        getUserDetail();

        getuserDetailWhileLoop();

    }


    private void getuserDetailWhileLoop()

    {
        if (EMAIL.isEmpty()){
            AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext);
            alert.setMessage("Email cannot be empty");
            alert.setCancelable(false);
            alert.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    dialog.dismiss();
                }
            });
            alert.show();
        }
        else{
            StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET,appURl2, new Response.Listener<String>()

            {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    try
                    {
                        JSONObject jo = new JSONObject( response );

                        for(int i =0 ;i < jo.length(); i++)
                        {


                            ID2 = jo.getString( "id" );
                            //NAME = jsonObject.getString("username");
                            //EMAIL = jsonObject.getString("user_email");
                            //CREATED_DATE = jsonObject.getString("created_date");



                            //sonObject = jsonObject.getJSONObject( "id" );
                            mid2.setText( ID2 );

                            //mName.setText(NAME);
                            //mEmail.setText(EMAIL);
                            //mDate.setText(CREATED_DATE);
                        }

                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

           }
```

Comment: Did you want to use **a TextView** for showing all the JSONObject in the Array?

Comment: yes. I want textview to show all the JSONObject in the Array

Comment: How about something like `String text = ""; for(int i =0 ;i < jo.length(); i++) { ..
text += ID2; }   mid2.setText( text );` ?

Comment: what happen to the i? there should be something like a code with i in it so there would be more than just 1 object array. however the code you gave does not show anything at the moment.

Comment: It's just a part of the code and was only an example for you. What your really need to do is add the code to your existing for loop code.

Comment: not working still.

Answer (score 0):

I like to use for loops over while loops, because with a for loop you're able to check the progress of the loop.

In this case it is best to use a for loop, just like you already did.
Can you post a example response of the StringRequest?

[EDIT]

You forgot to add the counter 'i', your for loop is fine.

```
JSONObject obj = jo.getJSONObject(i);
obj.getString("id");
```

I think this is the solution to your problem.

Comment: The problem is your JSON response not the loop, maybe the response is a JSONArray and not a JSONObject

Comment: this is  my json output. Is this json object?  {"id":"72","username":"tim"}{"id":"71","username":"tim"}{"id":"70","username":"tim"}{"id":"69","username":"tim"}{"id":"68","username":"tim"}{"id":"67","username":"tim"}{"id":"66","username":"tim"}{"id":"65","username":"tim"}{"id":"64","username":"tim"}{"id":"63","username":"matrix45832"}{"id":"62","username":"matrix4583"}{"id":"61","username":"thien
vu"}{"id":"73","username":"tim12345"}{"id":"74","username":"matrix123"}{"id":"75","username":"matrix123"}{"id":"76","username":"tim1234"}

Comment: for some reason it only produce one object which is id 70 and one username on andriod for the for loop.

Comment: Okay that is a JSONArray, if you change'this 'JSONObject jo = new JSONObject(response);' to 'JSONArray jo = new JSONArray(response);', maybe that is the problem

Comment: error. I put on top of the for loop and its giving me red color on JSONArray class and on the new JSONArray(response) as well.

Comment: i tried and its not working. here is the code.    for(int i =0 ;i < ja.length(); i++)
                        {

                            JSONObject jo1 = (JSONObject) ja.get(i);
                            ID2 = jo1.getString( "id" );
                            CONTENT = jo1.getString("Post Content");
                            //EMAIL = jsonObject.getString("user_email");
                            //CREATED_DATE = jsonObject.getString("created_date");

Comment: JSONObject jo = new JSONObject( response );
                        JSONArray ja = new JSONArray( response );

                        for(int i =0 ;i < jo.length(); i++)
                        {

                            JSONObject jo1 = (JSONObject) ja.get(i);
                            ID2 = jo1.getString( "id" );
                            CONTENT = jo1.getString("Post Content"); }

Comment: Did you try to log your response?

Comment: i did the debug and had a break at JsonObject jsonObject = new JSONobject(response) and the debug show response as '{"id":"293"}{"id":"292"}{"id":"291"}{"id":"290"}{"id":"289"}{"id":"288"}{"id":"287"}{"id":"286"}{"id":"285"}{"id":"284"}{"id":"283"}{"id":"282"}{"id":"281"}{"id":"280"}{"id":"279"}{"id":"278"}{"id":"277"}{"id":"276"}{"id":"273"}{"id":"272"}{"id":"271"}{"id":"269"}{"id":"268"}{"id":"267"}{"id":"266"}{"id":"265"}{"id":"264"}{"id":"263"}{"id":"262"}{"id":"261"}    but its not showing on text view for ID2 = jo1.getString( "id" );

Comment: So if you log the response '{"id":"293"}{"id":"292"}{"id":"291"}{"id":"290"}{"id":"289"}{"id":"288"}{"id":"287"}{"id":"286"}{"id":"285"}{"id":"284"}{"id":"283"}{"id":"282"}{"id":"281"}{"id":"280"}{"id":"279"}{"id":"278"}{"id":"277"}{"id":"276"}{"id":"273"}{"id":"272"}{"id":"271"}{"id":"269"}{"id":"268"}{"id":"267"}{"id":"266"}{"id":"265"}{"id":"264"}{"id":"263"}{"id":"262"}{"id":"261"}' is this the response?

Comment: Okay wait is was looking at your code, i saw 'ID2 = jo.getString( "id" );' that is not going to work because 'jo' is the full JSONObject, the for is basically doing nothing for you. You sould change it to 'ID2 = jo[i].getString( "id" );'

Comment: when i added jo[i].getString("id") I got an error with red on jo part.

Comment: My bad i was thinking php, use:`JSONObject obj = jo.getJSONObject(i);`, `obj.getString( "id" );`

Comment: i think we are getting close but the JSONObject obj = jo.getJSONObject(i); has an error for the i part. that code i put it inside the for loop.

Comment: here is the json that i want to show for ID2 {"id":"319"}{"id":"318"}{"id":"317"}{"id":"316"}{"id":"315"}{"id":"314"}{"id":"313"}{"id":"312"}{"id":"311"}{"id":"310"}{"id":"309"}{"id":"308"}{"id":"307"}{"id":"306"}{"id":"305"}{"id":"304"}{"id":"303"}{"id":"302"}{"id":"301"}{"id":"300"}

Comment: i had to change this into reyclerview to be able to see the list of the object. Its working now. Thanks for the help though Daan and everyone.